# Angular - fromEvent hands out 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'

Tags: angular, http, events, html-table, filtering

I'm trying to implement filtering in my data-table. I want to call the function loadSequences (contains my http call) when I write in the forms, in order to do so I got this function which should pick up keyup events. The function is used in the FormComponent (contains all the forms) which is a child of the SequencesComponent (in charge of showing the data on the table). I put the function in the FormComponent because that's where the keyup events happen, I hope that's how it works.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../sequences.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements /*AfterViewInit,*/ OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(SequencesComponent) private sequencesComponent: SequencesComponent) { }

  panelOpenState = false;
  formGroup!: FormGroup;

  sequenceId = '';
  asOrigin!: number;
  prefix!: string;
  suffix!: number;
  collectorIp!: string;
  collectorAsn!: string;
  durationGreater!: number;
  durationSmaller!: number;
  startDate!: Date;
  endDate!: Date;
  updates!: number;
  withdraws!: number;
  announces!: number;

  timerSubscription!: Subscription;

  @ViewChild('input') input!: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      sequenceId: new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern('[0-9a-fA-F]{24}')]),
      prefix: new FormControl(null/*, [Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9.:]{,20}((::)|.)/[0-9]{2}')]*/),
      collectorPeerIp: new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9]{5,}')]),
      asOrigin: new FormControl(null),
      suffix: new FormControl(null),
      collectorAsn: new FormControl(null),
      durationGreater: new FormControl(null),
      durationSmaller: new FormControl(null),
      startDate: new FormControl(null),
      endDate: new FormControl(null),
      updates: new FormControl(null),
      withdraws: new FormControl(null),
      announces: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    /*this.timerSubscription = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      map(() => {
        this.sequencesComponent.paginator.pageIndex = 0; // load data contains the http request
      })
    ).subscribe();*/
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(150),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => {
            this.sequencesComponent.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
            this.sequencesComponent.loadSequences();
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
  }
```

Here's the SequencesComponent (just the relevant parts):

```
export class SequencesComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(FormComponent)
  datiForm!: FormComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paginator.page.subscribe(x => this.loadSequences());
    this.loadSequences();
    this.dataSource.length.subscribe(x => this.paginator.length = x);
}

  loadSequences(): void{
    this.dataSource.loadSequences(this.paginator.pageIndex + 1, this.paginator.pageSize, '00', this.datiForm);
  }
```

Nothing happens when I write in the forms, opening the developer console I get the error 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'.

Comment: could you add a more complete code sample adding where it's currently used in your component?

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

use `this.input.target` instead.

Comment: I get the error 'property target does not exist on type elementref<any>'

Comment: i think your problem relates to timing.

Comment: put your code in ngAfterViewInit and try again.

Comment: It'already in ngAfterViewInit, I don't know why the property target isn't recognized